# How to display table sort up/down arrows properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[Sort arrows relatively close to each other](https://www.google.com/search?q=table%20sorting&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS3bKN9bnhAhWRM-wKHfMVC9wQ_AUIDigB&biw=1181&bih=608#imgrc=wWqaQr6elodyMM:)

```css
.up-arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  /* height: 10px; */
}

.down-arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="up-arrow" onclick="clickupArrow()">
      &#9650;
    </div>
    <div class="down-arrow" onclick="clickDownArrow()">
      &#9660;
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    function clickupArrow() {
      alert('up-arrow clicked');
    }

    function clickDownArrow() {
      alert('down-arrow clicked');
    }
  </script>
  
</body>
```

I am trying to display up/down sort arrays on table heads in html using react-fontawesome icons. Problem is they get displayed but with a "space" between them which does not look nice. Can they be displayed close to each other?

I've tried reducing the heights of divs but then it causes issues when user needs to click on any of these divs.

```
displayArrows = (sortKey, sortAsc, sortDesc) => {
    return (
      <div className="arrows-wrapper-div">
        <div
          style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
          role="button"
          onClick={(e) => sortAsc(e, sortKey)}
          tabIndex={0}
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretUp} />
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
          role="button"
          onClick={(e) => sortDesc(e, sortKey)}
          tabIndex={0}
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretDown} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

[sort up/down arrows right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8yiy.png)

Comment: Can you provide a full working example for us to work with? It's a bit tedious to re-create this example for ourselves in order to help you.

Comment: Okay, let me provide an example.

Comment: I've included a very simple example. Have a look at how the divs naturally have such height that they appear apart.

Comment: Play with the `line-height` property. Inspect the arrows on the browser's dev tools, maybe there's some margin or padding too.

Comment: There's no margin or padding added; it's the height of the div's content that's causing this issue. Playing with `line-height` of the both divs did make a difference though they are still apart then what I want them to be.

Comment: Adjest the position to relative and play with the top value. It should work

Comment: @Alen.Toma it can be used to reduce space but then it causes issues when you want to click on any one of them. Either both or one of them won't work.

Comment: Ok i have added a solution with css have a look an let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well dont know if this will work for you but here is a simple solution with css.

```css
.up-arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 7px black;
    border-top-width: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.down-arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: solid 5px transparent;
    background: transparent;
    border-top: solid 7px black;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    margin-top:1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="up-arrow" onclick="clickupArrow()">

    </div>
    <div class="down-arrow" onclick="clickDownArrow()">

    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    function clickupArrow() {
      alert('up-arrow clicked');
    }

    function clickDownArrow() {
      alert('down-arrow clicked');
    }
  </script>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You adjust your .up-arrow CSS like this:

```
.up-arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

Comment: Wow! How did you find out that?!

Comment: It didn't work. There's no margin present. Its the content that has height.

Comment: See my edit. What if you make it a negative margin?

Comment: Yes it reduces space but then clicking on arrows would produce unpredictable results. The up arrow doesn't remain clickable anymore in this case.